# angular binding failing on Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Angular JS is binding perfectly well in IE11 and in FireFox, no errors. But in Chrome, still no errors, the binding fails in the UI controls, but in the plane text dump, it renders fine.

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome binding failure]
**FireFox**
[image: FireFox binding perfect]
**IE11**
[image: IE binding perfect]
**Safari**
 Though I don't have an image, the binding works in Safari also.

I suspect that this has to be a script conflict, but I cannot seem to find it.
Here are my scripts that I am loading, and in the order of load.

1. jquery-{version}.js
2. jquery-ui-{version}.js
3. Common.js //Prototypes for IE 8 & 9 compatibility for Javascript Arrays
4. moment.js
5. moment-timezone.js
6. toastr.js
7. angular.js
8. angular-route.js
9. angular-resource.js
10. angular-recursion.js
11. angular-loader.js
12. angular-animate.js
13. angular-cookies.js
14. angular-sanitize.js
15. angular-scenario.js
16. angular-touch.js
17. angular-draganddrop.js
18. ui-bootstrap.js
19. ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
20. ui-utils.js
21. ui-utils-ieshiv.js
22. textAngular.js
23. textAngular-sanitize.js
24. app.js //My code
25. textAngularSettings.js /My settings

My Data structure for this control is:

```
task.details {
    buttonLabel:false,
    correctiveActionSection:true,
    correctiveActionTitle:"Corr Title",
    correctiveLabel:"Corr Lbl",
    deficiencyLabel:"Def Lbl",
    inspect:true,
    inspectionFailedLabel:"Insp Fail",
    inspectionPassedLabel:"Insp Pass",
    inspectionTitle:"Ins Title",
    inspectionUntestedLabel:"Inspect Untest",
    instance:[],
    notCleanedLabel:"Cleaned",
    noWorkLabel:"No Work",
    recleanedLabel:"Recleaned",
    role:{},
    showCorrectiveText:true,
    showDeficiencyText:true,
    sop:{},
    suppression:{},
    items:[
            {name:"a"},
            {name:"aa"},
            {name:"aaa", causeException:true},
            {name:"aaaa", causeException:true},
            {name:"aaaaa", causeException:true}
    ],
    inspection:{
            untested:"Inspect Untest",
            passed:"Insp Pass",
            failed:"Insp Fail"}}
```

My binding looks like

```
<label class="btn btn-default"
       ng-click="InspectClick('TestKey1', false)">
    {{task.details.inspection.untested}}
    <input type="radio" ng-checked="testKey1"
           ng-disabled="!testDisable1" />
</label>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'PreOpCtrl';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
        ['$scope', buildPreOpCtrl]);

    function buildPreOpCtrl($scope) {

        //task already exists, this is known because of this working on all other browsers.
        $scope.task.details = processDetails($scope.sourceData);
        $scope.InspectClick = InspectClick(svalue, bvalue);
    }

    function processDetails(details) {
        var ret = details;

        //Convert stringify to objects
        var i = ret.items;
        var t = JSON.parse(i);
        delete ret.items;   
        ret.items = t;

        //correct bools
        ret.showDeficiencyText = ret.showDeficiencyText === 'True' ? true : false;
        ret.showCorrectiveText = ret.showCorrectiveText === 'True' ? true : false;
        ret.correctiveActionSection = ret.correctiveActionSection === 'True' ? true : false;

        //breakdown for marshal at later time.
        ret.inspection = {
            untested: ret.inspectionUntestedLabel,
            passed: ret.inspectionPassedLabel,
            failed: ret.inspectionFailedLabel,
        };

        return ret;
    }

    //stub code. real code isn't written yet.
    function setInspectionException($scope)
    {
        return function (sval, bval) {
           console.log(sval,bval);
        };
    };

})();
```

There are no custom directives. No fancy code. I went out of my way to keep this as simple as possible.

**Update:** I have tried to change all of my ngIf directives to ngShow. The page slowed, but the problem didn't resolve.

Comment: Care to reproduce in a fiddle? Or atleast shows us the code.

Comment: @RahilWazir Thats the problem. there really isn't much code. At the base controller, I bind the task structure to scope, and the labels look like my sample. Since this is only affecting Chrome, and I have deadlines, After release, if this isn't resolved, I will will make a plunker demo.

Comment: @RahilWazir, I just realized that controller doesn't have much code, so I have just posted it. `$scope.sourceData` is known to populate because the areas that have "debug" watermarked are populated by it, after it is massaged through the controller. I had to sanitize some of the code, so there is a chance of a typo here.

Comment: @RahilWazir, there is one thing I notice in Chrome, and that is I have to go though several layers of $parent before I get to the actual object that contains the root for task. That is, Task exist in $scope, and detail is added to it in this controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this problem has been resolved with a newer release of Angular. I made no change to my code, updated to the latest release version, and the problem went away.

I still have no idea on what caused it.